# No solution stacks listed in elastic beanstalk configuration

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk

When setting my configuration for Elastic Beanstalk I am not given any options for the solution stack.

Here are the lines in question:

```
`Select a solution stack.
Available solution stacks are:
Select (1 to 0):`
```

Here is the entire output:

```
bret@ubuntu:~/myapp$ eb init
To get your AWS Access Key ID and Secret Access Key, 
visit "https://aws-portal.amazon.com/gp/aws/securityCredentials".
Enter your AWS Access Key ID: 
Enter your AWS Secret Access Key: 
Select an AWS Elastic Beanstalk service region.
Available service regions are:
1) US East (Virginia)
2) US West (Oregon)
3) US West (North California)
4) EU West (Ireland)
5) Asia Pacific (Singapore)
6) Asia Pacific (Tokyo)
7) Asia Pacific (Sydney)
8) South America (Sao Paulo)
Select (1 to 8): 1
Enter an AWS Elastic Beanstalk application name (auto-generated value is "myapp"): 
Enter an AWS Elastic Beanstalk environment name (auto-generated value is "myapp-env"): 
Select a solution stack.
Available solution stacks are:
Select (1 to 0):
```

I am running 32 bit Ubuntu 12.10 and AWS Elastic Beanstalk CLI tools version 2.4.0

Answer (score 79):

The credentials you use doesn't have administrator rights..

Go to Identity and Access Management (IAM) and add appropriate permissions to the user..

Comment: I have the same problem and my permissions are set to the highest permissions as administrator. Is there another solution to this problem? On mine, it didn't even show the "Available solution stacks are: Select (1 to 0):", it was completely blank after "Select a solution stack."

Comment: Just wondering, if you're dealing with multiple accounts for aws, is there a way to store these credentials in your repo instead of home dir ?

Answer (score 7):

I created an IAM user with access key and id, then click "Attach User Policy" and gave the account a PowerUserAccess.(I'm not sure what permissions are enough for "eb init")

Then typed "eb init" to run the procedure again, the solutions stacks appeared !!

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, like Michelle Glauser I didn't have any option numbers indicated at all.  Thinking that perhaps the problem was related to my having put my machine to sleep a few times during the 'eb init' process, I did CTRL+C to quit and re-tried 'eb init'.  The second time around, I was presented with a set of 31 options for the solution stack. In my case the options presented were:

```
Select a solution stack.
Available solution stacks are:
1) 64bit Amazon Linux 2014.03 v1.0.3 running PHP 5.5
2) 64bit Amazon Linux 2014.03 v1.0.3 running PHP 5.4
3) 32bit Amazon Linux 2014.03 v1.0.3 running PHP 5.5
4) 32bit Amazon Linux 2014.03 v1.0.3 running PHP 5.4
5) 32bit Amazon Linux running PHP 5.3
6) 64bit Amazon Linux running PHP 5.3
7) 64bit Amazon Linux 2014.03 v1.0.3 running Node.js
8) 32bit Amazon Linux 2014.03 v1.0.3 running Node.js
9) 64bit Windows Server 2008 R2 running IIS 7.5
10) 64bit Windows Server 2012 running IIS 8
11) 64bit Amazon Linux 2014.03 v1.0.3 running Tomcat 7 Java 7
12) 64bit Amazon Linux 2014.03 v1.0.3 running Tomcat 7 Java 6
13) 32bit Amazon Linux 2014.03 v1.0.3 running Tomcat 7 Java 7
14) 32bit Amazon Linux 2014.03 v1.0.3 running Tomcat 7 Java 6
15) 32bit Amazon Linux running Tomcat 7
16) 64bit Amazon Linux running Tomcat 7
17) 32bit Amazon Linux running Tomcat 6
18) 64bit Amazon Linux running Tomcat 6
19) 64bit Amazon Linux 2014.03 v1.0.3 running Python 2.7
20) 32bit Amazon Linux 2014.03 v1.0.3 running Python 2.7
21) 64bit Amazon Linux 2014.03 v1.0.3 running Python
22) 32bit Amazon Linux 2014.03 v1.0.3 running Python
23) 32bit Amazon Linux running Python
24) 64bit Amazon Linux running Python
25) 64bit Amazon Linux 2014.03 v1.0.4 running Ruby 2.0 (Puma)
26) 64bit Amazon Linux 2014.03 v1.0.3 running Ruby 2.0 (Passenger Standalone)
27) 64bit Amazon Linux 2014.03 v1.0.3 running Ruby 1.9.3
28) 32bit Amazon Linux 2014.03 v1.0.3 running Ruby 1.9.3
29) 32bit Amazon Linux 2014.02 v1.0.1 running Ruby 1.8.7
30) 64bit Amazon Linux 2014.02 v1.0.1 running Ruby 1.8.7
31) 64bit Amazon Linux 2014.03 v1.0.0 running Docker 1.0.0
Select (1 to 31): 25
```

It is also the case that I had not yet created any AWS Identity and Access Management (IAM) groups or users when I launched 'eb init' the first time around, although when I was asked by 'eb init' for keys is when I created those IAM entities.

Answer (score 3):

I also had a same problem.
And I solved it with following steps.

1. create Policy(AdministratorAccess)
2. attach it to user

https://console.aws.amazon.com/iam/home?region=us-east-1#policies

Answer (score 1):

1.Go to Users;
2.Attach Policy: select administratorAccess
3.ctrl + c to stop and restart from eb init!